# Insert inputboxes making code more interactive

Tags: vba, excel, inputbox

I am currently working on the following code which is searching through all tabs in an excel workbook, selects all currencies greater a certain threshold in a defined column "J" and if criteria is met the line containing the currency that is greater threshold is pasted in a new created tab called "summary".

Now my question is: 
1. Is there any chance to make this code more interactive? What I would like to do, is to add an inputbox in which the user is typing his threshold (in my example 1000000) and this threshold is used for looping through all tabs. 
2. It would be great to get an input box like "select column containing currency", as column "J" won't be set all time, it could also be another column ("I", "M" etc) however this will be the same for all sheets then.
3. Any chance to select certain sheets within workbook (STRG + "sheetx" "sheety" etc....) which are then pasted into my loop and all others are neglected?

Any help, especially for my issues within question 1 and 2 is appreciated. Question 3 would only be a "nice-to-have" thing

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = Sheets.Add
WS.Name = "Summary"

Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
With Sheets("Summary")
.Cells.Clear
End With

j = 2

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sh.Name <> "Summary" Then
        lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 4 To lastRow
            If sh.Range("J" & i) > 1000000 Or sh.Range("J" & i) < -1000000 Then
                sh.Range("a" & i & ":n" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summary").Range("A" & j)
                Sheets("Summary").Range("N" & j) = sh.Name
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next sh
Sheets("Summary").Columns("A:N").AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: As it stands, this is too broad.  You have 3 questions which should be asked separately.  Try to modify your code to answer the first question and, if successful, move on to the next one.  If your attempted modification doesn't work then post that specific question including the error messages or undesired behaviour.

Comment: You may be right, I'll try this approach.

Comment: You have two possible partial answers.  Even if they're right they are unlikely to be seen by a user searching for "Limit sheet loop to specific sheets" or "Select sheets to loop through".  Short succinct questions with clear titles will work for you and the SO community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a UserForm as input into the program - something like what follows.  You only need to run the 'CreateUserForm' sub once to get the UserForm1 event handlers set up in your spreadsheet.  Once that's done you can run the 'Test' to see the UserForm1 itself.  You can edit the event handlers to check the user input or reject it if need be.   Also once the UserForm1 is set up you can move the various labels and listboxes around and, of course, create new ones.  It should look like this:

[image: userform image]

You can select as many sheets as required from the last listbox and the selections will be added to a vba Collection.  See the MsgBox at the beginning of your code and play with entering values/selections into the user box to see what it does.

The UserForm handler that's called when you press the okay button will save the selections to global variables so that they can be picked up in the code.

```
Option Explicit

' Global Variables used by UserForm1
Public lst1BoxData As Variant
Public threshold As Integer
Public currencyCol As String
Public selectedSheets As Collection

' Only need to run this once.  It will create UserForm1.
' If run again it will needlessly create another user form that you don't need.
' Once it's run you can modify the event handlers by selecting the UserForm1
' object in the VBAProject Menu by right clicking on it and selecting 'View Code'

' Note that you can select multiple Sheets on the last listbox of the UserForm
' simply by holding down the shift key.
Sub CreateUserForm()
  Dim myForm As Object
  Dim X As Integer
  Dim Line As Integer

  'This is to stop screen flashing while creating form
  Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False

  Set myForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)

  'Create the User Form
  With myForm
   .Properties("Caption") = "Currency Settings"
   .Properties("Width") = 322
   .Properties("Height") = 110
  End With

  ' Create Label for threshold text box
   Dim thresholdLabel As Object
   Set thresholdLabel = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
   With thresholdLabel
     .Name = "lbl1"
     .Caption = "Input Threshold:"
     .Top = 6
     .Left = 6
     .Width = 72
   End With

  'Create TextBox for the threshold value
  Dim thresholdTextBox As Object
  Set thresholdTextBox = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.textbox.1")
  With thresholdTextBox
    .Name = "txt1"
    .Top = 18
    .Left = 6
    .Width = 75
    .Height = 16
    .Font.Size = 8
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .borderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
    .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
  End With

  ' Create Label for threshold text box
   Dim currencyLabel As Object
   Set currencyLabel = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
   With currencyLabel
     .Name = "lbl2"
     .Caption = "Currency Column:"
     .Top = 6
     .Left = 100
     .Width = 72
   End With

  'Create currency column ListBox
  Dim currencyListBox As Object
  Set currencyListBox = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.listbox.1")
  With currencyListBox
    .Name = "lst1"
    .Top = 18
    .Left = 102
    .Width = 52
    .Height = 55
    .Font.Size = 8
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .borderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
    .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
  End With

  ' Create Label for sheet text box
  Dim sheetLabel As Object
  Set sheetLabel = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
  With sheetLabel
    .Name = "lbl3"
    .Caption = "Select Sheets:"
    .Top = 6
    .Left = 175
    .Width = 72
  End With

  'Create currency column ListBox
  Dim sheetListBox As Object
  Set sheetListBox = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.listbox.1")
  With sheetListBox
    .Name = "lst3"
    .Top = 18
    .Left = 175
    .Width = 52
    .Height = 55
    .Font.Size = 8
    .MultiSelect = 1
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .borderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
    .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
  End With

  'Create Select Button
  Dim selectButton As Object
  Set selectButton = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
  With selectButton
    .Name = "cmd1"
    .Caption = "Okay"
    .Accelerator = "M"
    .Top = 30
    .Left = 252
    .Width = 53
    .Height = 20
    .Font.Size = 8
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
  End With

  ' This will create the initialization sub and the click event
  ' handler to write the UserForm selections into the global
  ' variables so they can be used by the code.
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 1, "Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()"
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 2, "   me.lst1.addItem ""Column I"" "
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 3, "   me.lst1.addItem ""Column J"" "
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 4, "   me.lst1.addItem ""Column M"" "
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 5, "   me.lst3.addItem ""Sheet X"" "
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 6, "   me.lst3.addItem ""Sheet Y"" "
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 7, "   lst1BoxData = Array(""I"", ""J"", ""M"")"
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 8, "End Sub"

  'add code for Command Button
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 9, "Private Sub cmd1_Click()"
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 10, "  threshold = CInt(Me.txt1.Value)"
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 11, "  currencyCol = lst1BoxData(Me.lst1.ListIndex)"
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 12, "  Set selectedSheets = New Collection"
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 13, "  For i = 0 To Me.lst3.ListCount - 1"
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 14, "    If Me.lst3.Selected(i) = True Then"
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 15, "      selectedSheets.Add Me.lst3.List(i)"
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 16, "    End If"
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 17, "  Next"
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 18, "  Unload Me"
  myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 19, "End Sub"

  'Add form to make it available
  VBA.UserForms.Add (myForm.Name)

End Sub

' This is your code verbatim except for now
' the UserForm is shown for selecting the
' 1) currency threshold, 2) the column letter
' and 3) the sheets you want to process.
' The MsgBox just shows you what you've
' selected just to demonstrate that it works.

Sub Test()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = Sheets.Add
WS.Name = "Summary"

Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
With Sheets("Summary")
  .Cells.Clear 
End With

'**** Start: Running & Checking UserForm Output ****
UserForm1.Show

Dim colItem As Variant
Dim colItems As String
For Each colItem In selectedSheets:
 colItems = colItems & " " & colItem
Next
MsgBox ("threshold=" & threshold & vbCrLf & _
        "currencyCol=" & currencyCol & vbCrLf & _
        "selectedSheets=" & colItems)
'**** End: Running & Checking UserForm Output ****

j = 2

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sh.Name <> "Summary" Then
        lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        For i = 4 To lastRow
            If sh.Range("J" & i) > 1000000 Or sh.Range("J" & i) < -1000000 Then
                sh.Range("a" & i & ":n" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summary").Range("A" & j)
                Sheets("Summary").Range("N" & j) = sh.Name
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next sh
Sheets("Summary").Columns("A:N").AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate your help! Unfortunately I have never worked with UserForms before and don't know how to get it running in my workbook

Comment: That's okay.  At any rate I've add a picture of what it looks like for others and should you want to revisit this in the future

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I am looking for! Do you have any idea how I can implement this into my project (xlsx test file attached in dropbox)? https://www.dropbox.com/s/ofngqkxz3accrso/Test.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: I can't open your spreadsheet as all my versions are corporate and I
could risk getting summarily canned if it had malware.  You can run
the code provided above. 
To get it to run you open a fresh spreadsheet.  Save it as macro
enabled which will create a new spreadsheet that now has a '.xlsm'
extension.  Close the regular xls spreadsheet and open the one with
the '.xlsm' extension. Create a new macro with any name and scrape the
above code into the window that pops up overwriting the empty sub that
excel provides (probably in 'Module1' under modules of the VBA editor).

Comment: The code has two macros
'CreateUserForm' and 'Test'.  You'll need to add in the Microsoft
Forms 2.0 Object Library.  To do that you go to the VBA editor go to
the Tools tab, click on the Browse button.  Go to C:\WINDOWS\system32\
and select the FM20.dll file and click Okay (as per this [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/482637-excel-2010-where-microsoft-forms-2-0-object-library.html) - bloody
arcane). Click Okay again and then run the 'CreateUserForm' macro.

Comment: Go back into VBA Editor and now on the Project window you should see a
'Forms' entry with 'UserForm1' in it (as mentioned you only need to
run this once).  If your okay up to here then run 'Test' macro and
the UserForm should show up.  Let me know if you encounter problem(s) on any of the steps in these 3 comments.   Also when the UserForm shows up enter a value for the threshold otherwise you'll get an error for the 'threshold' variable.  The UserForm code is robust but I'll leave the additional implementation details up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed instruction on this! One more thing. As a last step I have to insert the variables of the inputboxes (threshold, currencyCol and coItems) into my text sub right? I have to substitute the 1000000 with threshold, the "j" with CurrencyCol and `if sh.Name <> "Summary"` with `if sh.Name = colItems Then` am I right? As I don't have access to my laptop at the moment I am not able to work this out right now...

Comment: Yes for what you've said for the 'threshold' and 'currencyCol' variables - but not for collitems.  You want to use selectedSheets which is a VBA Collection which contains each of the sheets names you've selected in 'Select Sheets' listbox of the UserForm.  You can access each of the sheet names using indexing on 'selectedSheets'.  To get the first one you use 'selectedSheets(1)', second one 'selectedSheets(2)' etc).  At any rate you can google the Collection VBA data type - there's tons of examples to be had.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help on this. I'll try it out this weekend and accept your answer as soon as I get it working!

Comment: ok, so far i managed to create the userform by running 'createUserForm' once. After that I tried to run 'test' (modified as mentioned above) however if i click on "run" I get an error message saying: "Variable not defined" which is pointing on `for each colItem In selectedSheets:`? Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Did you see the userform?  That line is after the 'UserForm1.Show' command which should show you the form.

Comment: I tried it on my other laptop and it did work! Thanks for that! I just don't get why I have to define all sheets and column upfront? Is it possible that I can *enter* the column value and *select* sheets (in a way that the user form shows me all sheets that are currently in my workbook?! That's what I had initially in mind.

Comment: Glad you got it working - hard to got back to input-boxes once you get a user form working.  Yes you should be able to do that - preload the existing defaults so that you select whatever it is you need to change.  You'd have to change the code in the UserForm_Initialize sub of UserForm1.

Comment: I adjusted the userform in the way I need it. If I run Sub test I see the user form with the content I want to have, however if I select everything I want to have and click on the "Okay"-Button, I get an error message telling me that sub `click`is not defined?!..... Any idea what this could be? I couldn't figure it out?!

Comment: cmd1_click is defined.  It's one of the event handlers that's in UserForm1 - unless you've renamed the button.  The button name is set up in '.Name = "cmd1"' line of code.  You also can go into the editor of the userform to see if 'cmd1' is the name.   Basically the handler is just the name of the button with '_click' appended to it.  Not sure whether that helps with your problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim sheetsList As Variant
    Dim threshold As Long

    Set WS = GetSheet("Summary", True)
    sheetsList = Array("STRG","sheetx","sheety") '<--| fill this array with the sheets names to be looped through

    threshold = Application.InputBox("Input threshold", Type:=1)
    j = 2
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetsList)
        lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 4 To lastRow
            If sh.Range("J" & i) > threshold Or sh.Range("J" & i) < -threshold Then
                sh.Range("a" & i & ":n" & i).Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A" & j)
                WS.Range("N" & j) = sh.Name
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    Next sh
    WS.Columns("A:N").AutoFit
End Sub

Function GetSheet(shtName As String, Optional clearIt As Boolean = False) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetSheet = Worksheets(shtName)
    If GetSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set GetSheet = Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count))
        GetSheet.Name = shtName
    End If
    If clearIt Then GetSheet.UsedRange.Clear
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! This works fine, but is it also possible to insert an inputbox in which I can define the column that contains my currency values?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes it is possible and you can do much in the same way as it's been done for the threshold. I'm not by my PC but you try yourself and ask for help in case you get stuck. Finally you may want to mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: I figured it out. Appreciated your help on this, thank you!

Comment: If you have some time left, perhaps you may be able to have some ideas for my last problem with this code before it is finished: ;) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325891/vba-select-specific-sheets-within-workbook-to-loop-through

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for my purposes except the selection of single tabs to loop through:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim column As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim sheetsList As Variant
    Dim threshold As Long

    Set WS = GetSheet("Summary", True)

    threshold = Application.InputBox("Input threshold", Type:=1)
    column = Application.InputBox("Currency Column", Type:=2)
    j = 2
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If sh.Name <> "Summary" Then
            lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 4 To lastRow
                If sh.Range(column & i) > threshold Or sh.Range(column & i) < -threshold Then
                    sh.Range("a" & i & ":n" & i).Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A" & j)
                    WS.Range("N" & j) = sh.Name
                    j = j + 1
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next sh
    WS.Columns("A:N").AutoFit
End Sub

Function GetSheet(shtName As String, Optional clearIt As Boolean = False) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetSheet = Worksheets(shtName)
    If GetSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set GetSheet = Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        GetSheet.Name = shtName
    End If
    If clearIt Then GetSheet.UsedRange.Clear
End Function
```