# VBA - select specific sheets within workbook to loop through

Tags: vba, excel, inputbox

I have an excel workbook with a variable number of sheets. At the moment I am looping through all sheets and therein a specific column to search for figures above a certain threshold. Column and threshold are determined by inputboxes that need to be filled in by the user. If the figure in the column, let's say column "J" and row 10 is above threshold, row 10 is copied and pasted in a new created "summary" sheet etc.

I am struggling at the moment with a specific selection of sheets. I don't always want to loop through all sheets but instead would like to have another inputbox or something else in which I can select specific sheets (STRG + "sheetx" "sheety" etc...) that are looped through?! Anyone an idea how I can accomplish that with my code? I know that I have to change my "for each" statement to substitute for the selected sheets but I don't know how to create the inputbox to select specific tabs...

Any help appreciated!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim column As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim sheetsList As Variant
    Dim threshold As Long

    Set WS = GetSheet("Summary", True)

    threshold = Application.InputBox("Input threshold", Type:=1)
    column = Application.InputBox("Currency Column", Type:=2)
    j = 2
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If sh.Name <> "Summary" Then
            lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 4 To lastRow
                If sh.Range(column & i) > threshold Or sh.Range(column & i) < -threshold Then
                    sh.Range("a" & i & ":n" & i).Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A" & j)
                    WS.Range("N" & j) = sh.Name
                    j = j + 1
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next sh
    WS.Columns("A:N").AutoFit
End Sub

Function GetSheet(shtName As String, Optional clearIt As Boolean = False) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetSheet = Worksheets(shtName)
    If GetSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set GetSheet = Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        GetSheet.Name = shtName
    End If
    If clearIt Then GetSheet.UsedRange.Clear
End Function
```

Comment: Since youre data needs are starting to get more specific i suggest instead of using multiple input boxes, use a userform that has all the parameters on one pop up. That way you can fiddle with the userform controls which should provide you with more than enough options.

Comment: I know, I already got the suggestion to work with UserForms. However I have never been working with those before, that's why  I thought it would be possible to do a three step approach without UserForms (1. Prompt threshold, 2. prompt column 3. prompt sheets)...

Comment: userforms are easy. plus i think you'll appreciate the flexibility it will give you. The only thing you need to know how to do is pass control values to variables. easy as myVar = TextBox1.Value. try it out

Comment: How does the UserForm look?  Could you post a pic of it?  The UserForm code may help us - particularly how you Initialize it, call it and handle it on whatever event you are hanging off of.

Comment: Does that GetSheet function actually compile and work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the "NO-UserForm" *mood* you could use a combination of `Dictionary` object and the `Application.InputBox()` method when setting its `Type` parameter to `8` and have it accept `range` selections:

```
Function GetSheets() As Variant
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Do
          Set rng = Nothing
          Set rng = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select any range in wanted Sheet", title:="Sheets selection", Type:=8)
          .item(rng.Parent.Name) = rng.Address
        Loop While Not rng Is Nothing
        GetSheets = .keys
    End With
End Function
```

this function gets the `Parent` sheet name out of each range selected by the user switching through sheets and stops when the user clicks the `Cancel` button or closes the InputBox

to be exploited by your "main" sub as follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Sheets(GetSheets) '<--| here you call GetSheets() Function and have user select sheets to loop through
        MsgBox ws.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried it, however I am not sure how to implement the second part of your code into mine?! I substituted your Function for mine and adjusted the following part: `Set WS = GetSheets("Sample", True)

    threshold = Application.InputBox("Input threshold", Type:=1)
    column = Application.InputBox("Currency Column", Type:=2)
    j = 2
    For Each sh In Sheets(GetSheets)
        MsgBox sh.Name
        lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 4 To lastRow`
However I get an error referring to `Set WS = GetSheets...`

Comment: You are welcome. Change `Set ws = GetSheets("Sample", True)` to `Set ws = GetSheet("Sample", True)`, since you now have to differengt functions: `GetSheets() As Variant` that accepts no arguments and returns a `Variant` array and `GetSheet(shtName As String, Optional clearIt As Boolean = False) As Worksheet` that accepts one mandatory parameter and an optional one and returns a 'Worksheet' object. Finally if my answer solved your question you may want to mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your help on that! Now it works fine. Just one thing, isn't it somehow possible that I can simply select sheets with STRG + "sheetx" etc instead of clicking through all sheets that I want to loop through? If I have 10 or more sheets this is getting a little bit time-consuming.

Comment: make an example of the sheets names you want to select

Comment: @FlorianSchramm, I'd _never_ open an xlsm workbook from the web! Simply list possible names so as to find any common pattern

Comment: Ok, I thought this would be the most effective approach when you can see a testfile of what I am  talking about. The problem is that there are no actual common pattern among the sheets. The only common pattern would be that they are numbers ranging from 10000 to 1000000000. That's why I thought that selecting the sheets manually with (STRG + ...) would be the most effective way.

Comment: Then I actually can't understand what _"select sheets with STRG + "sheetx" "_  means. You may want to add some more examples

Comment: Ok, let me try to explain. My idea is that you have three inputboxes. One that asks for the threshold, than another one that asks for the column in which the figures to loop through will be and third the last inputbox asks for sheets to loop through. This could either be by selecting one or two by clicking on them or by using CTRL to select a whole bunch of sheets i.e. the last 20 tabs at the end of the workbook. Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that a UserForm could offer a more appealing way to define it, however the InputBox approach isn't bad. The following code creates an InputBox that accepts a sheet range entry in the same way as a print dialog accepts page numbers, i.e. either explicit sheet numbers separated by commas (1, 3, 9) or a range separated with a hyphen (1-9).

This will look like a lot of code but it's got some error handling to prevent ugly failures. Your loop `For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets` would be replaced by a loop like the example at the bottom of the code.

```
Sub sheetLoopInputBox()
    Dim mySheetsArr2(999)

    'Gather sheet range from inputbox:
    mySheets = Replace(InputBox("Enter sheet numbers you wish to work on, e.g.:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "1-3" & vbNewLine & _
    "1,3,5,7,15", "Sheets", ""), " ", "")

    If mySheets = "" Then Exit Sub 'user clicked cancel or entered a blank

    'Remove spaces from string:
    If InStr(mySheets, " ") Then mySheets = Replace(mySheets, " ", "")

    If InStr(mySheets, ",") Then
        'Comma separated values...
        'Create array:
        mySheetsArr1 = Split(mySheets, ",")
        'Test if user entered numbers by trying to do maths, and create final array:
        On Error Resume Next
        For i = 0 To UBound(mySheetsArr1)
            mySheetsArr2(i) = mySheetsArr1(i) * 1
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                MsgBox "Error, did not understand sheets entry."
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i
        i = i - 1
    ElseIf InStr(mySheets, "-") Then
        'Hyphen separated range values...
        'Check there's just one hyphen
        If Len(mySheets) <> (Len(Replace(mySheets, "-", "")) + 1) Then
            MsgBox "Error, did not understand sheets entry."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'Test if user entered numbers by trying to do maths:
        On Error Resume Next
        temp = Split(mySheets, "-")(0) * 1
        temp = Split(mySheets, "-")(1) * 1
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            MsgBox "Error, did not understand sheets entry."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        'Create final array:
        i = 0
        i = i - 1
        For j = Split(mySheets, "-")(0) * 1 To Split(mySheets, "-")(1) * 1
            i = i + 1
            mySheetsArr2(i) = j
        Next j
    End If


    'A loop to do your work:
    '(work through the sheet numbers stored in the array mySheetsArr2):
    For j = 0 To i
        'example1:
        MsgBox mySheetsArr2(j)

        'example2:
        'Sheets(mySheetsArr2(j)).Cells(1, 1).Value = Now()
        'Sheets(mySheetsArr2(j)).Columns("A:A").AutoFit
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, I understand your code, but how can I embed this into my code or rather make the reference to it? Proves to be not as easy as I thought with my given skills